# How to make plugin developer name available in templates?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm constructing a plug-in and I'm new to it.

I want to print to the screen in my template the name of the developer, by accessing the `getDeveloper()` method in my `Plugin.php`. The problem is instead of showing the name of the developer, it throws an error saying `Class Craft\CrmPortalVariable` not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data in plugins is not automatically made available to twig templates.

To make something available, you need to create a folder in your plugin master folder called `variables` and in that folder create a class `PluginNameVariable.php`

Here's an example of what you might put in that file:

```
<?php

namespace Craft;

class YourPluginNameVariable
{

    public function developerName()
    {
        return craft()->yourPluginsName->someServiceMethodThatReturnsTheDeveloperName();
    }

}
```

This would make a template variable available in your templates via

```
{{ craft.yourPluginName.developerName }}
```

Here are the Craft Docs for this - https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/variables

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I just followed what you've said but now, I'm getting an error  "Property "Craft\WebApp.crmportal" is not defined."

Comment: *crmportal is maybe my handle name for the plugin

Comment: Probable a case sensitivity issue.  Your best bet is to generate your plugin infrastructure using https://pluginfactory.io/ - this will give you all the structure correctly done & named, you just fill in the methods basically (choose variable in that!).  From there it's up to your PHP skills (start another question if you have different issues)

Comment: ok sir . i'll try that

Comment: I try using pluginfactory.io but nothing happens. it stays the same. having an error = " Property "Craft\WebApp.crmportal" is not defined. "

Comment: Add the twig causing the error